# What Would Beaches Look Like if Silicon Didn't Bond to Oxygen?

Tags: science-based, hard-science, chemistry, materials

I was on a beach recently and was contemplating what it would look like if Silicon **just didn't** bind oxygen very well/at all, perhaps similar to gold.

I'm not sure if something else would take the oxygen's place and create a similar environment to a beach, since silicon is very similar to carbon on the periodic table (Perhaps hydrogen due to its abundance?).

Silicon is also the second most abundant element in Earth's crust and has a high affinity for oxygen.

There need not be any fundamental shift in how chemistry works, perhaps an AI from the first civilization to ever exist in the universe just makes this so by subtly changing physical rules (To the extent such a thing actually exists) in the area  in the are to preserve how chemistry normally operated, just minus this one exception.

What exactly would a beach look like since it is mostly composed of SiO_2? Would beaches be more metallic in appearance? Would beaches remain mostly the same, but just with silicon bonded to other elements instead of oxygen?

Comment: ...we might not even have a planet upon which to have beaches! A large part of the Earth’s crust is SiO2

Comment: That doesn't mean that we wouldn't have a planet. The Si might still be there. I can't know what it would be like without the oxygen though. Even then, out AI might just limit this ti the region within the beaches.

Comment: "Even then, our AI might limit this to the region within the beaches."  The *exact* implementation details are going to matter here.  Done wrong one way, all the beaches freeze over as the AI has to provide bond energy to release the Si from the O.   Done wrong another way, you accidentally create an infinite energy machine and destroy the entire universe with it.

Comment: @CortAmmon No? If there are rules we don't understand being manipulated behind the scenes, *changing the rules* may require more energy than you'll get out of all the bonds reforming, thus averting infinite energy creation. *Also*, just because you *can* get infinite amounts of energy doesn't mean that you *currently have* infinite amounts of energy that tear the universe apart. We don't know for sure whether infinite energy is possible, *just that all attempts to make such a machine fail* There is *no guarantee* that the laws of thermodynamics are actually true.

Comment: Not all beaches are primarily silicon dioxide.  E.g. black sand beaches (various volcanic minerals), coral beaches (mostly calcium carbonate), limestone beaches, ones that have a lot of mica and feldspar...  And I imagine Titan might have beaches composed of water ice :-)

Comment: In order for silicon not to bind with oxygen, you have to.change chemistry. Nothing would be the same.

Comment: "Hard-science" for a question which starts from the premise that quantum electrodynamics doesn't work? And yet this question was typed on a computer which sent it to a world-spanning network. (Hint: it is indeed possible, almost certain, that there are many laws of physics which are not yet known. On the other hand we are absolutely certain that whatever those laws may be they don't affect the behavior of electrons under ordinary conditions.)

Comment: @SarahSzabo Here's an example of the kind of antics you have to deal with.  I go get some SiO2 from somewhere other than the beach region.  I throw the SiO2 onto the beach, let these new laws of physics take over and turn it into Si and O2 for me.  Let it turn the sand into silicion for me, releasing O2 into the atmosphere.  Then I take the silicon back outside of the beach, grind it up, and burn it, turning it back into SiO2 and generating energy to do work with.  Then I go back to the beach, and repeat.

Comment: You might be able to cobble together some really specialized reason why SIO2 is not thermodynamically preferrable in a global sense, but doing it in regions is going to be fraught with difficulty.

Comment: I think the way you stated your premise is not a good idea. What a bond is is kind of a fuzzy concept. I don't want to go into details, but it gets really complicated to define what you really want to avoid here. I think if you go down this road, you will soon find yourself backed into a corner you won't be able to get out of without such a detailed understanding of Chemistry that you are easily able to answer the question yourself. I think it is a legitimate question what other stuff beaches can be made out of or so, but you're going to attract a lot of criticism with that concept

Comment: This is like asking "What would 8 be like if you couldn't add 5 and 3?"

Comment: @CortAmmon Yes, and I've anticipated and replied to those ideas by saying that *changing the rules* may require energy. So: You take SiO2 into the field, the machine making the field loses 5 joules of energy and removes the Oxygen, then you take Si out of the field and burn Si in an oxygen atmosphere and release 3 joules stored in chemical potential energy. No infinite energy, no violations of the second law of thermodynamics.

Comment: @Spencer **It is not**. Positing, as an axiom that more advanced intelligences cannot  manipulate physics because they have a greater knowledge than us to "change" another field such as chemistry in such a subtle way contradicts history. Granted, this is a theoretical question, but I see no reason why the premise is impossible. Newtons laws were thought to be the end all, but Einstein came along and showed that things thought to be impossible by Newtonian mechanics were perfectly within the realm of plausibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer depends entirely on what magic you use.  The answer very well may be grains of silicon, exactly like [elemtilas posted](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/116866/2252).  However, It does appear that [silicon nitride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_nitride) forms bonds that are more [favorable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon#Chemistry_and_compounds) than the silicon-silicon bonds (322kJ/mol rather than 226 kJ/mol), so over time it might undergo that reaction.  The process of making silicon nitride is typically done at high temperatures (1850C), so the process may be very slow at room temperature.  Fortunately, when we're talking beaches, we can take our time.  It's geological scales!

I think the nitrogen bonds are the most likely result.  It's another common element, and it's gaseous meaning it will naturally be bathing the silicon grains at all times.  There are other silicon compounds out there, such as the silicides, but they bond to a metal, and that may not be a physically favorable reaction because the reagents would not often be in contact.

Of course, we will also have to account for the magic.  By [this estimate](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/math/how-many-grains-of-sand-are-on-earth-s-beaches?page=1), there's on the order of 700,000,000,000 cubic meters of sand on the world's beaches.  At 1602kg/m^3 [dry packed](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-density-of-sand),  that's 1,121,400,000,000,000kg of sand.  Assuming that's primarily SiO2, that's 0.06008kg/mol, thats about 16.6mol/kg, or 18,615,240,000,000,000mol of Silicon Dioxide.  At [roughly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_dioxide) 621kJ/mol of bond energy, that's 11,560,064,040,000,000,000kJ of energy to rip them apart.  Taking some zero's off, that's 11,560,064,040TJ, which is on the order of magnitude of "total fossil and nuclear energy sources on the planet."

So my point is, to spend that much energy, someone must have *really* been fed up with sand in their swim suit!

Comment: Great answer, I appreciate the humor as well. 

What state would you expect the Si3N4 appears to be a rather hard material. After a long time on geologic scales what state would the silicon nitride be in? Typical silicon dioxide is very granular but once it enters the field would it form flakes instead of fine grains or some other pattern?

Comment: @SarahSzabo I don't know enough about the compound to say for sure, but its particular hexagonal pattern (#173) appears to be shared by several compounds which wear gradually rather than fracture.  You might see a bunch of particles surrounded by the fine dust of sharp corners that got snapped off.  However, the structure also depends on *how* the oxygen gets taken off of the SI.  That's going to be a very invasive process with a lot of energy being thrown around.  I think you may be able to use author's discretion regarding what the Si's shape is going into the field

Comment: and I expect the shape of the Si going in will generally not change that much once it nitrates.

Comment: @Sarah Szabo: Typical SiO2 is not granular.  It occurs as various-sized crystals in rocks (search for "large quartz crystal" for examples), and as veins in e.g. granite.  It's only granular in beaches because it has been broken into pieces by erosion.  As I mentioned above, other materials can form sand.  (And as a curiousity, I have a roughly softball-sized quartz rock that I picked up from a beach in northern Norway, from a "beach" of similar-sized rocks, so not all "sand" is miniscule grains).

Comment: Your beaches will be invisible.

All of the strong rocks are based on SiO2. Without this, continental plates would simply not form, as the material that are composed of would be too weak to support themselves.

Lose all mountains, lose continental plate structures, and the whole world becomes one shallow sea.

All sea = no beaches.